# How to keep values in a dataframe based on values in another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe (dt) as follows

```
companimal  refanimal   X  studyday
b10         b1          2   1
b10         b1          9   2
b10         b1          4   3
b10         b1          4   4    
b10         b1          11  5
b10         b2          1   1
b10         b2          1   2
b10         b2          20  3
b10         b2          12  4
b10         b2          16  5
b10         b3          9   1
b10         b3          2   2
b10         b3          17  3
b10         b3          22  4
b10         b3          1   5
b10         b4          13  1
b10         b4          17  2
b10         b4          9   3
b10         b4          7   4
b10         b4          19  5
```

and a second dataframe (dt2) as follows

```
animal    lastday
b1          5
b2          3
b3          4
b4          3
```

I would like to go through dt and keep only those lines where dt$refanimal = dt2$animal & dt$study day <= dt2$last day

i.e.

```
companimal  refanimal   X  studyday
b10         b1          2   1
b10         b1          9   2
b10         b1          4   3
b10         b1          4   4    
b10         b1          11  5
b10         b2          1   1
b10         b2          1   2
b10         b2          20  3
b10         b3          9   1
b10         b3          2   2
b10         b3          17  3
b10         b3          22  4
b10         b4          13  1
b10         b4          17  2
b10         b4          9   3
```

I feel it should be straightforward but I can't work it out.

I've tried to do loops like the following

```
for (i in 1:nrow(dt)){
check = dt[i,]

  for (j in 1:nrow(dt2)){
    check2 = dt2[j,]
    if(check$refanimal == check2$animal & check$studyday <= 
check2$lastday){
dt$tmp == 1
    } else {
dt$tmp == "NA"
  }
```

In the hope that I could get another column of 1's & NAs in the original dt which I could then filter out but this doesn't work.. I realise there is probably a better way than this but I just couldn't work it out.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
df <- merge(dt, dt2, by.x = "refanimal", by.y = "animal")
subset(df, studyday <= lastday)
```

- `merge` does a join which brings the information of `lastday` over to the first dataframe. Call the result `df`.
- `subset` is a useful function in `base` R to filter (and select columns of) data. In this case you want all rows of that merged `df` where `studyday <= lastday`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea via `tidyverse`,

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 %>% 
 group_by(animal) %>% 
 expand(lastday = seq(lastday)) %>% 
 rename(refanimal = animal, studyday = lastday) %>% 
 inner_join(df1)
```

which gives,

> ```
> #Joining, by = c("refanimal", "studyday")
> # A tibble: 15 x 4
> # Groups:   refanimal [?]
>    refanimal studyday companimal     X
>    <fct>        <int> <fct>      <int>
>  1 b1               1 b10            2
>  2 b1               2 b10            9
>  3 b1               3 b10            4
>  4 b1               4 b10            4
>  5 b1               5 b10           11
>  6 b2               1 b10            1
>  7 b2               2 b10            1
>  8 b2               3 b10           20
>  9 b3               1 b10            9
> 10 b3               2 b10            2
> 11 b3               3 b10           17
> 12 b3               4 b10           22
> 13 b4               1 b10           13
> 14 b4               2 b10           17
> 15 b4               3 b10            9
> ```